# Android IABHelper vs Billingclient

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

In our android app, we are using in app billing using IabHelper wrapper library. Example 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive

Now, Google added newer version of the library with lot of changes to it.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html

Which version should we use? When will the Olderversion(v3) of the biller library expire?

Comment: I'm not sure I never used Play Billing Library yet but it's easier than In-app Billing API following a document. It's up to you!

Comment: YEs but our app already has implementation with iabhelper. Should i need to adopt to this version immediately? Is there any comparison available?

Comment: If you're using In-app Billing API, it seems that it's no need to update right now. I will find another sample as well and will share it then. thank you!

Comment: It seems google doesn't support IabHelper anymore. There are many issues in it. I hope google will fix issues and will update new library regularly.

Comment: Yes, We are getting issues thats why I was seeking for some updates. but they have released new library itself!!!

Answer (score 0):

As said on google official documentation, the AIDL way is/will not be supported anymore,

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate

> This topic describes how to migrate away from a billing integration
> that uses the Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL). Accessing
> Google Play's billing system using AIDL is deprecated, and all
> integrations must use the Google Play Billing Library in the future.

This link also includes a guid to migrate from AIDL to the new billing library.